# Looping in Python Error

Tags: python, python-3.4

I had to create a game of rock, paper, scissors in python with various menu options. I am having trouble with my program as it gets stuck looping through the main menu.

```
import random
import pickle


class GameStatus():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.tie = 0
        self.playerWon = 0
        self.pcWon = 0
        self.name = name

    def get_round(self):
        return self.tie + self.playerWon + self.pcWon + 1

# Displays program information, starts main play loop
def main():
    print ("Welcome to a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
    print ("What would you like to do?")
    print  ("") 
    game_status  = welcomemenu()
    while True:
        play(game_status)
        endGameSelect(game_status)

#prompt user's choice and return GameStatus instance
def welcomemenu():
    while True:
        print ("[1]: Start New Game")
        print ("[2]: Load Game")
        print ("[3]: Quit")
        print ("")
        menuselect = input("Enter choice: ")
        if menuselect in [1, 2, 3]:
            break
        else:
            print ("Wrong choice. select again.")

    if menuselect == 1:
        name = raw_input("What is your name?: ") 
        print ("Hello %s." % name)
        print ("Let's play!")
        game_status = GameStatus(name)
    elif menuselect == 2:
        while True:
            name = raw_input("What is your name?: ")
            try:
                player_file = open('%s.rsp' % name, 'r')
            except IOError:
                print ("name %s, your game could not be found") % name
                continue
            break
        print ("Welcome back %s.") % name
        print ("Let's play!") 
        game_status = pickle.load(player_file)
        displayScoreBoard(game_status)
        player_file.close()
    elif menuselect == 3:
        print ("Bye~!")
        exit()
        return

    return game_status


# displays the menu for user
    pcChoice = pcGenerate()
    outcome = evaluateGame(playerChoice, pcChoice)
    updateScoreBoard(outcome, game_status)


# prints the menu, the player selects a menu item, the input is validated, if the input is valid, returned the input, if
# the input is not valid, continue to prompt for a valid input
# 1 - rock
# 2 - paper
# 3 - scissors

def playerMenu():
    print ("Select a choice: \n [1]: Rock \n [2]: Paper \n [3]: Scissors\n") 
    menuSelect = input("What will it be? ")
    while not validateInput(menuSelect):
        invalidChoice(menuSelect)
        menuSelect = input("Enter a correct value: ")
    return menuSelect


# if the user doesn't input a 1-3 then return false, resulting in prompting the user for another value. If the value
# is valid, return True
# takes 1 argument
# menuSelection - value user entered prior
def validateInput(menuSelection):
    if menuSelection in [1, 2, 3]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# return a random integer 1-3 to determine pc selection
# 1 - rock
# 2 - paper
# 3 - scissors
def pcGenerate():
    pcChoice = random.randint(1,3)
    return pcChoice


# evaluate if the winner is pc or player or tie, return value accordingly
# 0 - tie
# 1 - player won
# 2 - pc won
def evaluateGame(playerChoice, pcChoice):
    rsp = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    win_statement  = ['Rock breaks scissors', 'Paper covers rock', 'Scissors cut paper']
    win_status = (playerChoice - pcChoice) % 3
    print ("You have chosen %s") % rsp[playerChoice - 1]
    what_to_say = ("Computer has chose %s") % rsp[pcChoice - 1] 
    if win_status == 0:
        what_to_say += (" as Well. TIE!")
    elif win_status == 1:
        what_to_say += (". %s. You WIN!") % win_statement[playerChoice - 1]
    else:
        what_to_say += (". %s. You LOSE!") % win_statement[pcChoice - 1]
    print (what_to_say)
    return win_status



# Update track of ties, player wins, and computer wins
def updateScoreBoard(outcome, game_status):
    if outcome == 0:
        game_status.tie += 1
    elif outcome == 1:
        game_status.playerWon += 1
    else:
        game_status.pcWon += 1

# If user input is invalid, let them know.
def invalidChoice(menuSelect):
    print ('menuselect, "is not a valid option. Please use 1-3')


# Print the scores before terminating the program.
def displayScoreBoard(game_status):
    print ("")
    print ("Statistics:")
    print ("Ties: %d") % game_status.tie
    print ("Player Wins: %d") % game_status.playerWon
    print ("Computer Wins: %d") % game_status.pcWon 
    if game_status.pcWon > 0:

        print ("Win/Loss Ratio: %f") % (float(game_status.playerWon) / game_status.pcWon) 
    else:
        print ("Win/Loss Ratio: ")
    print ("Rounds: %d") % game_status.get_round()

def endGameSelect(game_status):
    print ("")
    print ("[1]: Play again")
    print ("[2]: Statistics")
    print ("[3]: Quit")
    print ("")
    while True:
        menuselect = input("Enter choice: ")
        if menuselect in [1, 2, 3]:
            break
        else:
            print ("Wrong input.")
    if menuselect == 2:
        displayScoreBoard(game_status)
        endGameSelect(game_status)
    elif menuselect == 3:
        f = open("%s.rsp" % game_status.name, 'w')
        pickle.dump(game_status, f)
        f.close()
        print ("Bye!")
        endGameSelect(game_status)
        exit()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get an input from the user using `menuselect = input("Enter choice: ")`, python is expecting a string. Therefore, you need to change your code to compare the input to strings. For example:

```
def welcomemenu():
    while True:
        print("[1]: Start New Game")
        print("[2]: Load Game")
        print("[3]: Quit")
        print("")
        menuselect = input("Enter choice: ")
        if menuselect in ["1", "2", "3"]:
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong choice. select again.")

if menuselect == "1":
    name = input("What is your name?: ") 
    print("Hello %s." % name)
    print("Let's play!")
    game_status = GameStatus(name)
elif menuselect == "2":
    while True:
        name = input("What is your name?: ")
        try:
            player_file = open('%s.rsp' % name, 'r')
        except IOError:
            print("name %s, your game could not be found") % name
            continue
        break
    print("Welcome back %s.") % name
    print("Let's play!")
```

The program accepts my input when I make those changes, but it looks like you have not specified the `play()` function yet in your while loop, so that will lead to another error

```
while True:
    play(game_status)  <-- This line will error, since there is no play function
    endGameSelect(game_status)
```

**EDIT**

As kolokkol has also commented, the `raw_input()` is no longer used in Python 3.x, so change all instances to `input()`

I hope this helps!